# Excel time format using Epplus

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, import, epplus

I have an excel document which I try to import to my system.
(.net core 2.2 and EPPlus v4.5.3.1)

> The excel data like 09:57:32 and Custom Cell format [hh]:mm:ss

```
private TimeSpan? GetRequiredTimeFromRowOrNull(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int row, int column, string columnName, StringBuilder exceptionMessage)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, column].Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm:ss";
        var cellValue = TimeSpan.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value.ToString());

        if (cellValue.ToString() != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cellValue.ToString()))
        {
            return cellValue;
        }

        exceptionMessage.Append(GetLocalizedExceptionMessagePart(columnName));
        return null;
    }
```

> "worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value"
>   comes 0.414953703703704

and also

> "worksheet.Cells[row, column].Text" comes 09:12:32

How can I get exact value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel stores dates and time in decimal values.  The whole-number part is the day and the decimal part is the time.

So, to get into a C# `DateTime`, use the OLE Automation converter:

```
try
{
    var val = (double)worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value;
    var dt = DateTime.FromOADate(val);
    var cellValue = dt.TimeOfDay;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //log conversion error
}
```

Will want to put a `Try.Catch` around the cast JIC the cell does not have a number in it.